# Eclipse autocomplete not working for variables within classes

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, autocomplete

For some reason my Eclipse IDE (oxygen 4.7.0) is not giving autocomplete options for variables within classes on C/C++ projects. It works fine for java projects.

So a variable outside a class will be autocompleted anywhere in the code but a variable (or function) within a class (i.e. `classInstance.foo`) will not be autocompleted unless I am typing within that class constructor. I just get the box saying "no default proposals".

Is there anything I can do to fix this behavior?
I've tried cleaning and restarting. I can't see anything that would change this in the autocomplete settings for C/C++.

Comment: C does not have classes.

Comment: Did you rerun the indexer?

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm aware C doesn't have classes but Eclipse bunches C and C++ settings together.

Comment: @mch I've manually toggled the indexer checkbox as per your suggestion but no luck.

Comment: Here's an old [link](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/748781/) ... does it fix your problem?

Comment: Hi @TonyB, I have all the auto activation checkboxes on. Still no luck.

Comment: If the file extension is `.c` instead of `.C`, `.cpp`, etc., Eclipse assumes it is C not C++. See _[Eclipse help: File Types preference (C/C++)](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_c_file_types.htm)_.

Comment: hi @Howlger The filetype is currently .cpp but I changed it back and forth a few times to no avail!

Comment: When I create a `cpp` file that contains `class foo { int var1=1; int var2=var};` and the cursor is between `var` and `}`, then code completion proposes me as expected `var1` and `var2`. Do you get other proposals for this example? If yes, which proposals? If no, could you make an example that shows your problem?